# Cluster is causing my query to run SLOWER then before

Tags: oracle

So I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now and I have no clue what to do. I am doing university homework that requires us to create a unoptomized sql query (does not have to make sense) and then apply index's and see if it makes it faster (which it did for me, from 0.70 elapsed time to 0.66) and then we had to apply clusters.

I applied clusters and it has now almost doubled the amount taken to finish the query. From 0.70 to 1.15. **Below is how I specified my cluster**:

```
CREATE CLUSTER customer2_custid25 (custid NUMBER(8))  

SIZE 270

TABLESPACE student_ts;
```

I tried all my previous times with INITIAL and NEXT but that seemed not to make a difference.  **Below are the tables**:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER18 ( 

    CustID         NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(15),
    SURNAME     VARCHAR2(15),
    ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(20),
    PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER(12)) 

    CLUSTER customer2_custid25(CustID); 

CREATE TABLE product18( 

    ProdID     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    PName    Varchar2(6),
    PDesc    Varchar2(15),
    Price    Number(8),
    QOH        Number(5)); 

CREATE TABLE sales18( 

    SaleID     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    SaleDate    DATE,
    Qty            Number(5),
    SellPrice    Number(10),
    CustID        NUMBER(8),
    ProdID        NUMBER(10)) 

    CLUSTER customer2_custid25(CustID); 
 

CREATE INDEX customer2_custid_clusterindxqg ON CLUSTER customer2_custid25 TABLESPACE student_ts ;
```

**Base Query:**

```
SELECT  
    AVG(s.sellprice), s.qty, c.custid 
FROM 
    SALES s, CUSTOMER2 c 
WHERE  
    c.custid = s.custid 
GROUP BY  
    s.qty, s.qty, c.custid 
HAVING 
    AVG(sellprice) > (SELECT MIN(AVG(price)) 
                      FROM product  
                      WHERE pname in  
                    (SELECT pname  
                       FROM product 
                       GROUP BY pname  
                       HAVING pname LIKE 'FA%') 
                       GROUP BY price);
```

I also tried taking the tablespace section in the cluster index away.

**I followed this formula to help calculate cluster sizes**:

> "Size of a cluster is the size of a parent row + (size of Child row *
> average number of children). "

This brought me to the size of 270. However, after testing sizes (going up 20) from 250 to 350 I found 320 to be the fastest at 1.15.

---

No matter what I try, I can not for the love of me get it lower then my base query times.

Other students have done the same and halved their query time.

All help is really appreciated.

Comment: What was your base set/query?

Comment: Can not believe I left this out, let me add it.

Comment: All added, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: too many things for Comment.  Moving to chat.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/115256/oracle-cluster-tables?tab=general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Chat Recap

According to the Plan, the CBO decided to *not* take advantage of the data being in a `CLUSTER`.

Comment: Sorry everyone for not commenting this, I was sapposed to. However, I got sucked further into figuring out how to fix it. After contacting one of my lecturers (and 2 hours of help later!) we found out that the issue went away completely when she simply replicated my exact tables and queries but just on her side. The issue, as Michael put it though (from his findings) was that the CBO was not taking advnatage of the data being in a cluster. No clue how replicating everything changed that haha! THank you so much for all the help Michael, you were awesome.